# Logical Operators and increment operators

Tags: c, logical-operators

Can anyone explain this code? How value is assigned to only variable m but the output is for all variables change. Also the roles of logical operator and increment operators over here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
int main() 
{ 
    int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m; 
    m = ++i || ++j && ++k; 
    printf("%d%d%d%d\n", i, j, k, m); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Remember that the **logical** operators do [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and that any non-zero value is considered true.

Comment: There are no bitwise operators in this code. And you seem to no understand what the pre-fix increment operators do?

Comment: What do you expect? Where is the problem? Did you read about logical operators and know how pre/post increment works? What contradicts your textbook or other reliably documentation?

Comment: Unrelated: empty parentheses in a function declarator are an obsolescence feature and subject to be removed in a futher version of the language. Don't get used to this bad practice. Us a proper prototype-style declarator, i.e. `int main(void)`. Of course this applies to all function declarations (which includes definitions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`||` or logical OR operator has a [short-circuit property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). It only evaluated the RHS is the LHS is FALSY.

In your case, the evaluation of `++x` produces a value of `-2`, which is not FALSY (0). Hence, the RHS is never evaluated.

To break it down:

```
m = ++i || ++j && ++k; 

 >> m = (++i) || (++j && ++k);
     >> m = (-2) || (++j && ++k);
        >> m = 1   // -2 != 0
```

So, only the value of `m` and `i` are changed, remaining variables will retain their values (as they are not evaluated).

That said, the result of the logical OR operator is either `0` or `1`, an integer value. The result is stored in `m`, in your case.

Comment: I don’t think this is what he asked . He’s asking how is it that only m is being reassigned but every variable changes.

Comment: @sagi but, every variable is not changing!!

Comment: yes @sagi this was my doubt

Comment: Can you please explain it in an elaborated way

Comment: You know what ? I think ++ has a higher precedence, so they actually are changing @suaravghosh

Comment: @sagi how that makes the evaluation of RHS of `||` possible?

Comment: @sagi Run the code and check the output ... you're mistaken.

Comment: My bad, should have checked from the start.

Comment: reason behind the downvote?